# Why in HIVE joins take significant time in execution?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am trying to join two table in hive having almost same number of records. The query is taking a long time for execution.
Why in hive JOINS take a long time to execute?
The number of records is approx 50k in both tables.

Comment: Why this question was downvoted? Please bother to add useful comments on how the question can be improved. My five cents: Please add more details: the query, how long is it running, query plan

Answer (score -1):

Hive query converts to Map Reduce internally and gets executed because of which it will take few mins to execute it. There are different ways by which you can improve the performance. You can follow this [link](https://hortonworks.com/blog/5-ways-make-hive-queries-run-faster/) to improve your query performance.

The main reason for using hive or Hadoop is handling huge volume of data. So you will be seeing definitely huge performance gain as compared to other relational databases when you are handling huge data. But for the amount of data which you are mentioning probably is not a good usecase for Hive.

Comment: I agree with you that map reduce is not meant for small number of records but the joins I am doing is a subset of huge dataset. This data is a filtered data  from huge dataset. But I have to join two tables in order to get a single set.

Comment: Joining data in Hive is absolutely fine. From what you mentioning here in comments, i am guessing that you are having filtering criteria to filter out your records. So you can use partitions and bucketing based on the columns you are joining while creating your table which will further improve its performance.